# How do I store and view graphically formatted data?

Tags: delphi, text, graphics, viewer, formatted

I have an app (written in D2010) which is similar to a text retrieval app... It has a list of questions, with their corresponding answers.  Most answers are strictly text, but some answers have graphics, and formatting.  My dilemma has to do with the formatted answer.  The user should be able to copy this answer (formatting and graphics) in order to paste it into another app.  I have tried using a Word OCX.  This is a little problematic.  User has to have word, it gives random errors when using inside a virtual machine, etc.  I am now playing with using a built in browser component, and viewing the data as a PDF.  This is nice and easy, but when I copy and paste it, I loose all formatting, and the graphic shows up as a large totally black box.

I can store the data in whatever format I choose.  It is stored as a BLOB in a DB file.  I write it to a temp file and then I call some type of viewing routine, so I have flexibility there.  My issue is really, what viewer mechanism is simple to implement, and allows copying/pasting, while maintaining text formatting (bullets, indents, etc) and graphics.

Thanks,
GS

Comment: You are searching for a word processor which can copy and paste formatted text with grphics? You may have a look at http://www.wptools.com/. I use this component for quite a long time now and it is mature and powerful.

Answer (score 1):

The TRichEdit (or any of TRichEdit descendants or similar classes) will allow the users to visualize text formatting and images, and when the content is copied, the RTF representation of the data will be copied into the clipboard.

When the clipboard data is pasted into a RTF compatible text editor (like Wordpad and Word), all the formatting, bullets and images are preserved.

Comment: RichEdit seems to handle text and formatting, but not able to handle graphics... or am I mising something?

Comment: The RTF format is able to handle graphics, images, and embed any other file via OLE. But the standard Delphi TRichEdit has some limitations.If you could use JediVCL (or other third part rich edit control) you can try yourself: open wordpad, insert text, bullets, images/graphics and save the RTF file. In your application add     YourJvRichEdit.LoadFromFile('C:\YourFile.RTF');    , and all RTF content will be handled.

Comment: That's because of [`Rich Edit control version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787873(v=vs.85).aspx#re_versions) used by the `TRichEdit` component in Delphi. The one from JVCL uses a newer version than the one from Delphi. [`François Gaillard`](http://stackoverflow.com/users/9842/francois) wrote a nice post [`Using Richedit 4.1 with D2010`](http://fgaillard.com/2010/09/using-richedit-4-1-with-d2010/) explaining how to *upgrade* your rich edit control in Delphi 2010.